# Improving Async/Await Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm working on a data analytics dashboard in Node.js as a portfolio piece. I've built a pipeline that gets the data where it needs to be for more processing, however, I feel the below code can be improved but it overlaps with my inexperience with Node.js and async/await.

The below code looks redundant to my eye. I tried to move the second function into the first in an anonymous async function to no avail, and was wondering if the more experience members here had any suggestions?

```
async function readFilteredStream() {
    filteredStream = streamConnect(); //Connects to API
    const results = await readStream(filteredStream); //Reads in a sample of data and closes the connection. 
    return { data: results };
}

async function respondWithSamples() {
    const results = await readFilteredStream();
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ES6, when you have a variable that's going to be used as a property of an object, you can use the same variable name as the property so as to use shorthand syntax, if you want:

```
const data = await readStream(filteredStream); //Reads in a sample of data and closes the connection. 
return { data };
```

You do:

```
filteredStream = streamConnect();
```

You are assigning to an outer variable named `filteredStream`. Do you declare and use `filteredStream` elsewhere? If not, then this is a bug - you're either implicitly creating a property on the global object, or (if you enable strict mode), an error will be thrown. Always declare variables before using them. You might have wanted to do:

```
async function readFilteredStream() {
    const filteredStream = streamConnect(); //Connects to API
    const data = await readStream(filteredStream); //Reads in a sample of data and closes the connection. 
    return { data };
}
```

The `respondWithSamples` function doesn't do anything useful. It calls `readFilteredStream` and returns it. It would be easier and make more sense to just use `readFilteredStream` instead, and remove `respondWithSamples` - all you're doing is creating another wrapper around the Promise, one which will be resolved wherever the Promise is unwrapped.

Answer (score 2):

I would refactor the second function to simply:

```
const readFilteredStream = ()=> streamConnect().then(readStream)
```

Imho much more readable.

There's really no point into creating an object with a single key `data`, it can be done directly on the result of the function call.